# I wanted to reverse my array. Why this code gives garbage value?

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm, vector, reverse

```
    #include <iostream>


    using namespace std;

    int main(){

    int n;
    int a[n];
    cin>>n;
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++){
        cin>>a[i];
    }
    for(int i=n;i>=0;i--){
       cout<<a[i]<<" ";
   }
    }
```

Input:- 4
1 2 3 4
Output 4199008 4 3 2 1

Comment: Enable warnings on your compiler. `int a[n];` isn't supported by every compiler and should generate a warning, if not an error. You don't initialize `n` first. You actually want `std::vector<int>`. Also, [do not use `using namespace std;`](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1452721/501250). You can reverse any container that supports bidirectional iteration using [`std::reverse()`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/reverse).

Comment: Also, your second loop indexes `a[n]`, which is UB. you need to start at `n-1`.

Comment: Your code clearly does not attempt to "reverse the array".   See std::reverse.  After applying it, cout the resulting array, first to last.  This simplifies and documents your coding intent, and avoids the unintended Undefined Behavior.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For starters the program has undefined behavior because the variable `n` is not initialized

```
int n;
```

So this declaration

```
int a[n];
```

is invalid. Moreover variable length arrays is not a standard C++ feature. Instead use the standard class template `std::vector`.

Also within this loop

```
for(int i=n;i>=0;i--) {
   cout<<a[i]<<" ";
}
```

you are trying to access of non-existent element with the index `n`.

Also you are not reversing an array. You are trying to output an array in the reverse order.

Pay attention to that there are standard algorithms `std::reverse` and `std::reverse_copy` declared in the header `<algorithm>`.

Here is an example how your program with using your approach could look

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of an array ";

    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> v( n );

    std::cout << "Enter " << n << " elements: ";

    for ( auto &item : v ) std::cin >> item;

    std::cout << "The array in the reverse order\n";

    for ( size_t i = v.size(); i != 0;  )
    {
        std::cout << v[--i] << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look like

```
Enter the size of an array 10
Enter 10 elements: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
The array in the reverse order
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

If to use standard algorithms then your program can look the following way

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <iterator>
#include <algorithm>

int main() 
{
    size_t n = 0;

    std::cout << "Enter the size of an array ";

    std::cin >> n;

    std::vector<int> v( n );

    std::cout << "Enter " << n << " elements: ";

    std::copy_n( std::istream_iterator<int>( std::cin ), n, std::begin( v ) );

    std::cout << "The array in the reverse order\n";

    std::reverse_copy( std::begin( v ), std::end( v ), 
                       std::ostream_iterator<int>( std::cout, " ") );
    std::cout << '\n';

    return 0;
}
```

The program output might look the same way as shown above

```
Enter the size of an array 10
Enter 10 elements: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
The array in the reverse order
9 8 7 6 5 4 3 2 1 0
```

Comment: Honorable mention: `rbegin()` and `rend()` which make `reverse_copy` completely unnecessary.

Answer (score 1):

`a[n]` will return the element after the last one. When you iterate in reverse order, start with `i=n-1`.

Comment: There's more that needs to be fixed, e.g. the `int a[n]` before `n` is initialized. Even initializing it would not work unless `n` is `const`.

Answer (score 0):

At the beginig of your program there is a mistake:

```
    int n; // You declare n with no value
    int a[n]; // You use is
    cin>>n; // After you used it you get your value-
```

Now i can suppose that that was just an error while copying it because you give inputs and outputs

> Input:- 4 1 2 3 4 Output 4199008 4 3 2 1

So forgeting about that, you declare an array of size n. **Remember that the elemnts of the array will go from 0 to n-1.** Now look at your second for loop

```
    // the first element you acces is n and you stop at 1
    // but the array goes from n-1 to 0
    for(int i=n;i>=0;i--){
       cout<<a[i]<<" ";
    }
```

So you still get n values as an output but the first element that you access is outside of the array. Thats why you get a garbage value, that is a value that was left there.

A solution will be to change the for loop

```
    for(int i=n-1;i>=-1;i--){
       cout<<a[i]<<" ";
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

While reversing the array start the loop from n-1 that is i=n-1 (n is the no of elements in array). And run the loop till i>=0. If you will start loop from n it will read illegal index which is out of range and will give you garbage value.

```
 for(int i=n-1; i>=0; i++){
      cout<<arr[i]<<" ";}
```